# Binding mode of a TextBox Text property should default to TwoWay

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp, mvvm-light

I'm creating a simple MvvmLight/UWP project.

My model is the Article class :

```
public class Article : ObservableObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    string référence;
    public string Référence
    {
        get { return référence; }
        set
        {
            if (référence == value)
                return;
            référence = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string désignation;
    public string Désignation
    {
        get { return désignation; }
        set
        {
            if (désignation == value)
                return;
            désignation = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my view :

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniversalTest1.UWP.Articles"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="UniversalTest1.UWP.Articles.Article_Detail"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UniversalTest1.Data.ViewModels.Articles;assembly=UniversalTest1.Data"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ArticleViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Référence :"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Désignation :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Article.Référence, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Article.Désignation, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>

        <Button Content="Sauver" Command="{Binding SauverCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Notice the **Mode=TwoWay** parameter in the binding for the 2 text boxes. If I don't use it, I get a OneWay binding.

Shouldn't the binding for a TextBox.Text property default to TwoWay ?

Many thanks in advance,
Julien

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) article, the default Binding mode for {Binding} is OneWay while the {x:Bind} has a default mode of OneTime.

So, you do need to explicitly set your mode to **TwoWay** if you need that on your bindings.

Comment: Alex, according to [the official .Net documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx), _In general, user-editable control properties, such as those of text boxes and check boxes, default to two-way bindings_

Comment: Correct, that is the .NET documentation (WPF) - and in WPF Text Binding is TwoWay by default.UWP is different and the official documentetion for UWP is in the link I provided.

Comment: Alex, if you're right, this is nonsense to me. I can think about some situations where you would use a TextBox and not use a two way binding (a readonly textbox where the user can select and copy the text, but not edit it ...), but this should definitely not be the default behavior IMHO.

Comment: TwoWay bindings are computationally expensive because of the observers needed to run them. Because performance is really important in UWP, (since apps can run on a wide range of devices) the default binding mode defaults to OneWay or OneTime so that developers have to make a conscious decision to enable them

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I thought so too.  But safest is to explicitly set what binding mode you want as it changes from property to property.  Just a recommendation.